# How to access a nested string?

Tags: python, list, nested

```
grid = [ ['x'] * w ] * h
grid[0[2]] = 'a'
```

This was a test to make a grid-like structure. The thing is, I can't access a nested list because integers can't be subscripted. I've seen problems like this but they aren't a recalling problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: After you learn to access it you'll have to learn about mutable objects... Just sayin'

Comment: What JBernando is probably saying is that you cannot use `[...]*n` for mutable objects if you plan to modify the string, or else every other instance of that string in your grid will automatically change from under you. To elaborate, strings are effectively immutable in python, so it's not `['x']*w` that's the problem, but if `rows = [['a','b','c']]*3`, and you modify a row, all the other rows will change. Use `[['x' for c in range(numCols)] for r in range(numRows)]`.

Comment: ...addendum: `[['x']*3 for c in range(numCols)]` also works since the inner list is recreated each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have meant:

```
grid[0][2] = 'a'
```

That would take the first element in 'grid' (a list), and set its 3rd element (at position 2) to 'a'